# How to move a canvas element up and down for a certain amount of time with javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make 6 guitars strings move when they are clicked on. I tried doing a simple animation by moving the string 2.5 px up and 2.5 px down for 3 seconds. but I don't really know how to do that.

This is what I've tried:

```
function onLoad(){ 
    snaren();
    snaarAanraken();
}

function snaren(){
    var c = document.getElementById("strings");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    for (var i=1;i<7;i++){ //drawing the 6 strings
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0,42.5*i);
        ctx.lineTo(700,42.5*i);
        ctx.stroke();
    }   
}
function snaarAanraken(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("strings");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasLeft = canvas.offsetLeft;
    var canvasTop = canvas.offsetTop;
    canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var x = event.pageX - canvasLeft;
        var y = event.pageY - canvasTop;
        console.log(x, y);
        if (x >= 0 && x<= 700) {
            if (y >= 35 && y<= 50) {//check if clicked on first string
                var e = new Audio("e2.mp3");
                e.play();
                var canvas_y = 42.5;
                var bewegen = setInterval(function () {
                    if (canvas_y > 44) {
                        canvas_y = 40
                    }   
                    if (canvas_y < 41) {
                        canvas_y = 45;
                    }    
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 60);
                    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(0,canvas_y);
                    ctx.lineTo(700,canvas_y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    console.log(canvas_y);
                }, 100);
            clearInterval(bewegen, 3000); 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I made a small example of a vibrating guitar string. It waits 2 seconds then strums the string, which vibrates for half a second.

The problem you have in your code is that you're adding a time-variable to your clearInterval, which isn't possible. If you want a delay on clearing an interval, you need to couple it with `setTimeout`, kind of like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(bewegen);
},3000);
```

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = 300;
c.height = 400;

var tremble = 2;

var myInterval;

function strum() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    
    drawString();
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,50+tremble);
    ctx.lineTo(c.width,50+tremble);
    ctx.stroke();
    tremble*=-1;
}

function drawString() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,50);
    ctx.lineTo(c.width,50);
    ctx.stroke();
}

drawString();

setTimeout(function() {
 myInterval = setInterval(strum,16);
    setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
        drawString();        
    },500);
},2000);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a guitar string you could use quadratic curve coupled with a sine function. The radius for the sine function could be controlled with time.

Also use requestAnimationFrame for good fluid animation. You're not using setTimeout correctly (rAF also provide a high-resolution time as argument which you can use instead of Date.now or performance.now() - not shown).

## Example

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

(function play() {
  renderString(75, 20, 5000, function() {
    setTimeout(play, 250);
  });
})();

// provide y position, max radius, time in ms and a callback function for done
function renderString(y, max, ms, callback) {

  var w = ctx.canvas.width,
      h = ctx.canvas.height,
      f = 0,                                                // fake frequency (demo)
      startTime = Date.now();
  
  (function loop() {

    var t = 1 - ((Date.now() - startTime) / ms);            // normalized time progress
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);                              // clear frame
    ctx.beginPath();                                        // new path
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);                                       // start of curve
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(w * 0.5, y + getSine() * t, w, y); // quad. curve
    ctx.stroke();                                           // stroke it
       
    if (t > 0) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    else callback();
  })();
                    
  function getSine() {
    return Math.sin((f=f+2)) * max;   // todo: use real frequency
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```